# What is Java API name for a class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java

Java examples have lots of classes from APIs. I am recently trying to use spring framework. I am trying out an example for bootstrap loader in Spring with org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. But I could not search for the API related to this. This is not only a time, I have been through with this kind of problem.

Is there any proper way to find the api for a class?

Answer (score 0):

here's the API link for the latest Spring Core Framework [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/).  Google is your friend so just "java 6 api" in Google will get you a long way and the same goes for the majority of components.

incidentally, Eclipse and a lot of IDE's give you access to known Javadoc's for classes, so try your favorite IDE too.